# Don't overwrite files with Kettle SFTP

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

I'm using the "Get a file with SFTP" step in Kettle to retrieve files for a job. An additional file is uploaded to this SFTP every day. I'd only like the job to download and transform the new file. I noticed there is an option to "Don't overwrite files" in the "Get a file with FTP" step, but I don't see a similar option for SFTP. Is there any way to replicate this don't overwrite feature?

Thanks.

Comment: You could get a list of the files on the server, a list of the files on your system, merge the streams and compare for new files on the server, then get only those from the sftp server by passing in the filenames in the stream. However, if it's possible in the ftp step to do this but not the sftp, I would recommend filing a ticket with Pentaho to get this corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lftp).

After logging in, use

```
mirror -R --ignore-time local/dir/path remote/dir/path
```

and be sure not to append slashes to the paths.

This will resume uploading whatever directory you were trying to put.

Type

```
man lftp
```

For more information